# I can't see the drop down menu of my add-on in Blender 2.8

Tags: add-on, versions

I work recently on the passage of my add - ones in the version 2.80 (formerly 2.79), however, when I click on the furniture or equipments menu, the pop-up menu does not display, while with the version 2.79 the menu displayed. Do I need change something in my scripts?

#Here is the script

```
import bpy
import os.path
import os
from ..properties.properties import *
from ..operators.filepath import Pathname

def update_pathname(path):
    """
        This function updates the path of the images.
        
        :param path: New path of the file
        :return: None
        :rtype: None
    """
    for pcoll in preview_collections.values():
        bpy.utils.previews.remove(pcoll)
    preview_collections.clear()

    pcoll = bpy.utils.previews.new()
    pcoll.images_location = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), path)
    bpy.types.Scene.pathname = pcoll.images_location
    preview_collections["thumbnail_previews"] = pcoll

    bpy.types.Scene.my_thumbnails = EnumProperty(
        items=generate_previews(),
        )

class FurnitureMenu(bpy.types.Menu):
    bl_idname="Furniture_Menu"
    bl_label = "Objects Menu"    
    """
        This class is a drop down menu which displays the furnitures of the objects' library.
    """  
    def update_enum(self,path):
        items = []
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
            for file in files :
                items.append((file,file,""))

    def draw(self,context):
        """
            This function gets the name of all the subdirectories and displays them in a menu.
            :return: None
            :rtype: None
        """
        layout=self.layout
        getString = bpy.context.preferences.addons["addons_SIMPLE version 2-80"].preferences.librarypath
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(getString+"Furniture"):
            for dirname in dirs :
                layout.operator("wm.filesname",text=dirname).filesname = "\\Furniture\\"+dirname


class EquipmentMenu(bpy.types.Menu):
    bl_idname="Equipment_Menu"
    bl_label = "Objects Menu"
    """
        This class is a drop down menu which displays the equipment of the objects' library.
    """      
    def draw(self,context):
        """
            This function gets the name of all the subdirectories and displays them in a menu.
            :return: None
            :rtype: None
        """
        layout=self.layout
        getString = bpy.context.preferences.addons["addons_SIMPLE version 2-80"].preferences.librarypath
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(getString+"\\Equipment"):
            for dirname in dirs :
                layout.operator("wm.filesname",text=dirname).filesname = "\\Equipment\\"+dirname
```

Comment: Without testing this `getString = bpy.context.preferences.addons["addons_SIMPLE version 2-80"]`  looks dodgy.... since the addon name also needs to be a valid python module name.  (btw also at issue is using hardcoded backslash windows only paths)  See https://medium.com/@ageitgey/python-3-quick-tip-the-easy-way-to-deal-with-file-paths-on-windows-mac-and-linux-11a072b58d5f